# c++ Unhandled exception

Tags: c++, c++11

hello im new user of c++ and i have a problem
i want to read a text file into vector. this file have 57 000 line and i get this problem

> Unhandled exception at 0x764d4dbd in project 2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x007ceb48..

this is my coding

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <malloc.h>
using namespace std;

const int m = 17000;
const int n = 2;

std::vector< vector<long double> > student (m, vector<long double>(m,n));

ifstream inpStud("Carleton91.stu");
ofstream outData ("output.txt");

void readstudent(){

    long double k, numline;
        //assign all data to an array
    for (int i= 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for (int j= 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            inpStud >> student[i][j];   
            k=student[i][j];    
        }

        //count number of exam
        if ((k==2) && (i>100)){
                numline = i;
                break;

        }
    }

    //print data
    for (int i= 0; i<numline; i++)
    {
        for (int j= 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            outData << student[i][j] << "    ";
        }
        outData << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{

    readstudent();

    inpStud.close();
    outData.close();
    return 0;
```

i dint know what is the actual problem is..please someone help me with this..thanks

this is the file [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xoqw73diw2dq6hp/Carleton91.stu)

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. Compile with all warnings and debug info enabled.

Comment: You are reading data from a file, therefore we have no way to know what data you're using.  Also, the `numline` variable is uninitialized, and there is no guarantee it will get set to anything.  However, you use `numline` in your `print data` for loop as if it was set to a value.

Comment: A 17000 * 17000 vector of `long double`s? That's more than 2GB. My psychic powers say that you are compiling this as a 32-bit program, and that therefore you are out of user mode address space.

Comment: hello @BasileStarynkevitch.. i try that and its error at vector i dont know why..

Comment: @shuthairah: You need to learn how to debug programs when it doesn't do what you want. When things go wrong, you don't have to look at the entire program at once. Remove parts of the program that do not contribute to the error. In this case, remove all the file reading logic. Your problem is almost certainly in the declaration of the `student` variable.

Comment: hello @T.C., for that actually i used 2GB ram and its can go for 16000 but went i chang the laptop that have 8GB its only can go untill 10000..

Comment: `hello im new user of c++ and i have a problem i want to read a text file into vector. this file have 57 000 line`.  If this is what you want to do, there are much better ways to accomplish this.  Your code is trying to do much more than merely read data from a file -- to be more honest, it's too convoluted to just be a "file reading" program.

Comment: @shuthairah: Even on machines with more than 2GB of memory, 32-bit programs cannot access all that memory at once because 32-bit pointers can only address up to 4 GB, and 2 GB of that space is reserved for the operating system. Are you really planning to work with more than 2 GB of data with your program? At that point you need to use techniques and algorithms specifically designed to work with that much data.

Comment: Are you seriously considering that each student has 17000 marks?

Comment: @shuthairah There are plenty of 32-bit C++ programs that process millions of lines, not a mere 57,000.  Maybe you should state exactly what you're trying to do, instead of posting a "solution" that you are trying to get to work.

Comment: I somehow doubt that you need more than 2GB of memory to process a 600KB data file.

Comment: hello @PaulMcKenzie, actually there will be more coding if the program can read that file into vector..

Comment: @T.C. now im using 8GB of memory.. how much memory i need to have actually??

Comment: @shuthairah: I'm going to have to be frank. What you need to do first is to do *less coding*. What you need is *more understanding* of the problem you're trying to solve. Step back and think through the data structures needed for your problem. Do you really need a 17000 x 17000 array to process student marks? Does a human teacher in real-life calculate marks on a 17000 x 17000 spreadsheet?

Comment: @shuthairah - You're still looking for an answer to your "solution".  I'm asking you, what is your program supposed to be doing with this data?  What is the purpose/goal of the program?  Maybe it is impossible to read *all* this data into a vector.  Maybe you need to use a data base?  Maybe, maybe, maybe... Therefore please explain the problem, not your "solution"

Comment: Well, his loops never iterate past the first `n` (2) members of each of the vectors....

Comment: @Insilico.. actually in new in c++..so i have to change the algorithm..means that i have to do it again right??

Comment: maybe you need replace `std::vector< vector<long double> > student (m, vector<long double>(m,n));` by `std::vector< vector<long double> > student (m, vector<long double>(n));`

Comment: @shuthairah I took a look at your file. It has over 57000 lines, with 2 numbers per line. So I have no idea where you came up with 17000. What you need is a `struct` with 2 data members, one for each number on a line. Then create a `vector` of these `struct`s, and instead of setting an initial size and using `vector::operator[]`, read each line into a temporary `struct` instance, and `vector::push_back` it. You really should start reading the documentation to get familiar with the classes you're using before diving in headlong and writing code.

Comment: @shuthairah: Don't worry about C++ right now. The syntax can be taken care of. The bigger problem is that you don't seem to understand what your program needs to actually do. As PaulMcKenzie said, think about the goal of the program. Understand what is being asked from you. Once you do that, you can then think of what data structures and algorithms you need. All of this can be done without regard to the programming language. Software engineers don't write code then think about the problem. The code-writing step is the very last step.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie.. im going to built a university exam timetable using dataset file..first i need to read the file..so u said i have to change the vector and using something else??

Comment: @shuthairah - You need to describe what that input file you have a link to is supposed to denote.  It is a file of 2 columns, both with integer values.  I see no need for `double` anywhere.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, so i have to erase doublle?

Comment: @shuthairah: You still haven't answered our questions for clarification. What does the data in the `Carleton91.stu` file represent? What kind of information do you want to produce based on this file? You said you're building an exam timetable based on this file. That sounds like something that can be really useful for students. How about you tell us more about the file's contents and the timetable?

Comment: @shuthairah - I'm asking what do the numbers in the file mean?  You have one column of values, and a second column of values.  What exactly do these mean?  For example, the first three lines:  `1 0261` `1 0262` `2 0660`  So what are the definition of these values?

Comment: @shuthairah - Are you attempting to store multiple integers per student?  If so, is the first column the "student number" followed by the data for that student?  If so, then you're better of using a `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>`, than just a std::vector.

Comment: @Insilico oh im sory..1st line represent a number of student and the 2nd line represent the course code that the student take...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  oh im sory..1st line represent a number of student and the 2nd line represent the course code that the student take..mean that student 1 take course 0261

Comment: @shuthairah - So you want to have each student to reference multiple course codes?  Student 1 has more than 1 course.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes.. student 1 take course 0261 and 0262

Answer (score 1):

```
const int m = 17000;
const int n = 2;

std::vector< vector<long double> > student (m, vector<long double>(m,n));
```

This creates a `vector` of `vector<long double>`s containing 17000 vectors, with each vector in turn containing 17000 `long double`s, each initialized to 2.

`long double`s are usually at least 8 bytes each, depending on the system. Let's take the lower bound for now. Ignoring all overhead from `vector`, you are allocating space to store 17000 * 17000 = 289 million `long double` values; assuming 8 byte per `long double` that's 2.312 billion bytes, or about 2.15GB.

The user-mode address space of a 32-bit program on Windows is usually 2GB (32-bit pointers can only address 4GB, and half of that is reserved for operating system use), which means that the program can't possibly allocate all that memory. One of the allocations fails, throwing a `std::bad_alloc` exception, causing the error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you want to do is store multiple values for each student, then the better choice would be to use a `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>`.  This way, you have a single student mapped to a vector of all of the data associated with the student.

Since the data seems to be just an int, then a `vector<int>` is all the data item in the map needs to represent.

The following code works with your file with no issues (if the file URL link becomes broken, the file consists of lines of two integers -- the first is the student number, the second integer is the course number):

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::map<int, std::vector<int>> MapIntToVector;

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    MapIntToVector m_mapIntVect;
    ifstream ifs("Carleton91.stu");
    int studentNumber, studentCourse;
    while (ifs)
    {
        ifs >> studentNumber >> studentCourse;
        m_mapIntVect[studentNumber].push_back(studentCourse);
    }
    // output data
    MapIntToVector::iterator it = m_mapIntVect.begin();
    while (it != m_mapVect.end())
    {
        cout << "Here is student " << it->first << " course(s) taken: ";
        std::copy(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
        cout << "\n";
        ++it;
    }
}
```

This inputs and outputs the students read in from the file.

The input portion just creates a new entry in the map whenever a new student number is encountered.  Regardless of whether the student entry is new or not, the data item is pushed onto the vector associated with the student.

I leave it to you to do research on containers such as `std::map`.